# Define a section-like command with three parameters

Tags: macros, sectioning

I'm looking to define a section-like command for a CV document that takes
three arguments: role, company, and time - like shown below. Because I lack
the TeX experience I used the `titlesec` package but it feels a little
forced as section titles don't have three parameters.

My own attempt in TeX, show below as `\exp`, works kind of but breaks down
in situations where it needs to be clever about page breaks and other
corner cases. I was not able to reverse engineer the code that `titlesec`
uses and would be grateful for a direct implementation of such a title
command. It doesn't need to create a TOC entry.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}

\titlespacing*{\subsection}{0pt}{*2}{0pt}
\titleformat{\subsection}
    {\normalfont\sffamily}
    {}{0pt}{#1}
\def\experience#1#2#3{\subsection{\textbf{#3} -- #1\hfill #2}}

\begin{document}


\experience{Startup Inc.}{June 2013 -- June 2015}{Developer}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy
eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam
voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet
clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit
amet. 

\def\exp#1#2#3{
    \ifhmode\par\fi
    \removelastskip
    \vskip2ex plus 0.5ex minus 0.3 ex\goodbreak
    \hbox to \hsize{\sffamily\textbf{#3} -- #1\hfill #2}
    \nobreak}

\exp{Startup Inc.}{June 2013 -- June 2015}{Developer}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy
eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam
voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet
clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit
amet. 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What's the problem in using the `\experience` command?

Comment: out of topic: `\exp` is already defined in `amsmath`package. It is not good idea to use the same name for different purposes, regardless that you probably not use in your CV :-)

Comment: @egreg There is no problem per se in terms of the result. I just feel that this is not what `titlesec` was made for or supports and I'm curious how this would be implemented in either TeX or LaTeX. @Zarko: I just picked something as I didn't want to override `\experience` such that we can keep them apart in the discussion.

Comment: Are you sticking to `\experience` as wrapper for a `\subsection` or should `\subsection` be changed as well?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer `\experience` can be a macro totally on its own; I don't need `\subsection` and only used it to implement `\experience` in terms of section commands provided by `titlesec`.

Comment: @ChristianLindig: A (stupid???) solution would be to use a `tabularx` with total linewidth as the heading of your `experience` entry. The page-breaking occurs in the additional statements below (where you used `\lipsum` as placeholder), I assume, but this might look awkward anyway

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I'd prefer a more low-level solution. After all, section titles should be something TeX was designed for.

Comment: @ChristianLindig: You could take a look into `latex.ltx`, especially for `\@startsection` and `@sect`, but the easiest way is to grab `\subsection` in a `\let` statement and make a wrapper around it, using `\subsection*` always

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A proposition, but of course not really perfect (too many design issues not clear)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{letltxmacro}


\makeatletter
\LetLtxMacro\orig@subsection\subsection

\NewDocumentCommand{\experience}{mmm+m}{%
  \orig@subsection*{\textbf{#3}  -- #1\hfill #2}
#4%
}
\makeatother



\begin{document}


\experience{Startup Inc.}{June 2013 -- June 2015}{Developer}{%

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy
eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam
voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet
clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit
amet. 
}

\experience{\LaTeXe\ Inc.}{June 1997 -- June 2060}{Core user}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy
eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam
voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet
clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit
amet. 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The main problem here is not to allow page breaks between the title and the text; I see nothing bad in using `\subsection`, as the document seems to be a CV.

I'd suggest an environment, so you can decide later whether allowing page breaks in the body.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{titlesec}

\titlespacing*{\subsection}{0pt}{*2}{0pt}
\titleformat{\subsection}
    {\normalfont\sffamily}
    {}{0pt}{}


\newenvironment{experience}[3]
 {\subsection{\textbf{#3} -- #1\hfill #2}}
 {\par}

\begin{document}


\begin{experience}{Startup Inc.}{June 2013 -- June 2015}{Developer}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy
eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam
voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet
clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit
amet.
\end{experience}

\begin{experience}{Startup Inc.}{June 2013 -- June 2015}{Developer}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy
eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam
voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet
clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit
amet.
\end{experience}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can ensure no page breaks with

```
\newenvironment{experience}[3]
 {\subsection{\textbf{#3} -- #1\hfill #2}
  \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}}
 {\end{minipage}\par}
```